# Boundary terms in integration by parts for the fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, semigroups-of-operators, fractional-calculus

Let $u,v \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and assume that $v$ is compactly supported inside a domain $\Omega$.
Is it true that
$$
\int_\Omega v (-\Delta)^su \, d x = \int_\Omega (-\Delta)^{s/2}v(-\Delta)^{s/2}u \, dx,
$$
where $(-\Delta)^s$ denotes the *spectral* fractional Laplacian with either Dirichlet or Neumann bounary conditions? Moreover, is it true that
$$
\int_K v (-\Delta)^su \, d x = \int_K (-\Delta)^{s/2}v(-\Delta)^{s/2}u \, dx,
$$
if $\mathrm{supp}(v) \subseteq K \subset \Omega$?